# Verb to express a user uploading a request for a "necessity"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, false-friend

I'm working on a system where the users can add necessities, for example, the necessity of a  professional to provide some service that is needed for the treatment of a patient (e.g.: a dermatologist).

In a literal translation from Spanish, it would be something like "Register necessity" ("*Registrar Necesidad*"), but it sounds a bit awkward for me in English.

1) Is it okay?
2) Is there a more precise way to say it? "Register a necessity" maybe?

Comment: How about "Register a Requirement"?

Comment: My wild guess is you probably meant "license"; perhaps those necessities you mentioned are "required licenses".

Comment: So, the patient has seen a general doctor who has recommended a specialist after he has diagnosed the patient and the system needs to record the first doctor's recommendation? In the US this is called a "referral".

Comment: Request a Referral. Make a Referral. It depends on the exact scenario. Your description is too vague.

Comment: @ColleenV it's a previous phase. First an user registers that a professional is needed to provided some medical treatment, then other person will search and choose the candidates, also referring one of them. I'm asking for the first action.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> Request Additional Services

To me *register* is more like "registration" that you do to get access to a system. It is not really like what you are doing here, as I would assume the system already knows who you are.

Comment: *Request*, though, implies that it may be denied, and that someone else will approve or deny this request.  It's possible that is what the OP is aiming for, but I might guess that the Spanish "registrar" is being used here more in the sense of "write a record for" in English, in which case you'd use something like "Add Additional Services" (in the sense of "adding" the referral to the record being edited), or even just "Add Services" if you didn't want to imply that the services might be superfluous or unnecessary (or if you needed a shorter phrase for a button on a screen).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct when you say that "Register a necessity" sounds awkward in English.  In your specific example, we would probably say "Request a Specialist" or "make an appointment with a specialist."  "Request a Service" would be more general.  Context is important here; in some cases we might say "Sign up for" or "Register for" or "Reserve" a service or requirement.